# Clone a github repository, then upload it to my own repository

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a repository to download the code, now I want to work on it and save it in my own private repository on Github. I don't want to contribute to the original project or submit changes or anything, it's just a personal project. When I try to do this, however, my git isn't working because I think it's already associated with the repository that I did the clone command from. How do I properly do what I'm talking about?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/

Comment: You can just do `git remote set-url origin [your git URL]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to appear as a fork of the repo, you can change your git origin :

```
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin git@github.yourusername/yourproject.git
$ git config master.remote origin
$ git config master.merge refs/heads/master
```

You can then push to yourusername/yourproject